# Can't disable screen compatibility mode in android

Tags: android

I am developing an App for all screen sizes and dpi.

The problem is that for large/smaller screen than normal the UI is being scaled, meaning I think screen compatibility mode is enabled.

This is my goal: I have an image button that is 90 pixels in height, so I think it is 90 dp in normal-mdpi device and I want it to remain 90 dp in larger and smaller screen sizes. So to the eye, the size remains the same.

The problem I am having is that is looks good (90 dp) in normal-mdpi device, but it looks much bigger and with scaling artifacts in a large-mdpi device.

I am targeting min android OS of 2.3.3, therefore I have the following manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<!--
    If not set explictly, screen compatibility mode would be enabled for
    large screen, which is scaling of normal
-->
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

According to the android documentation, if targeting 10 or below, you mush specify supports-screens otherwise compatibility mode is enabled by default. Problem is that I am specifying it but I am still getting the compatibility mode enabled.

Any ideas? Please let me know if my understanding is wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figure I post an answer after a whole day of debugging.

For me, the issue seem to be the emulator. When you launch the ADV, you need to calculate the actual screen device size and know your monitor dpi so you can set it in the launch options. 
Once I did this, the image button that I had specified as "x dp" in my layout and having "x pixels" in the PNG, looks the same size (in) in all screen sizes and densities.

If you would like to get rid of artifacts due to android scaling, you can provide your own images in the ldpi, hdpi, xhdpi folders with their corresponding scaling already applied.

To calculate the device screen size, use the resolution and density provided in the launch options dialog, then calculate with this formula: (looks painful but it works, you can measure with a ruler in your computer monitor and the device if x in, will be x in in your ruler)
screen size = sqrt ( (w in pixels/ dpi)^2 + (h in pixels/dpi)^2)
where w, and h is the resolution in pixels

To calculate your monitor dpi, I googled my computer type. For mac book pro 15.4 in, it is 128 and for an apple cinema display 27 in it is 109. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The method I used to keep all of my images the same size is to use the regular display getWidth and getHeight methods to set a variable.  Then I set my images using Bitmap.createScaledBitmap to a % of the screen size.  Regardless of the dpi it will look the same.  On a 240 dpi screen that is that is 16:9, to get the same image on a 480 dpi 16:9 screen would be double the dpi.

I am using these images on a canvas, but I would guess they would be similar.  Also in doing animations and such it is important when not in GL.  I had to redo my current game because when I played it on a lesser dpi it moved so fast it was like lightning!  Moving 10 pixels on a 180 vs a 240 was an eye opener.